# Sending UDP packets through a NAT

Tags: udp, ip, protocols, nat

I am trying to send a UDP packet to a device that is behind a NAT. Using a 3rd party program it is possible to send packets to this device no problem, and the packets show up in wireshark fine.

Using my own UDP client to send a packet to the device doesn't work... but if the device sends ME a packet, in the onReceive() method, sending directly back to the device in this method DOES work...but interestingly if I take the EndPoint and connect to this using a new UDP client, then it doesn't work again.

It seems like only when the device connects to me can I send messages downstream (like reverse connecting in TCP) and even taking the EndPoint as a reference to the 'connection' is not enough.

**Can anyone think of reasons why I can't send directly to the device, even though I know it is possible to do so because the 3rd party software can do it?**

Sending directly to other IP's such as my local computer works fine too, it is just this device that I cannot contact. My local computer is on an address like 192.168.10.2 and the device is on an address like 12.0.1.5 (when connected it creates its own LAN)

Many thanks

Comment: Consider checking if the 3rdparty uses UPnP to set up the router. It is all a question about the router configuration.

Comment: The 3rd party does not seem to use UPnP. But the device itself does have a DHCP server onboard, if that helps

Comment: Maybe there is a fixed redirection set up in the router? Check any virtual servers with corresponding UDP (TCP/UDP) ports.